# In SQL Server, which query performs better?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

--Suppose I want to:

```
UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 1 WHERE ID = 187
```

--OR I can accomplish the same by

```
UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 1 WHERE Bar <> 1 AND ID = 187
```

--OR I can accomplish the same by

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE Bar <> 1 AND ID = 187)
UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 1 WHERE ID = 187
```

Assuming the queries above are all valid and have the same behavior (I know they might behave differently with certain triggers or with other database activity), is there a performance reason to choose one?  What if Bar is already 1 most of the time this runs?

The 2nd query seems like it would perform better and have fewer writes, but I'd assume SQL is smart enough to optimize this.

The 3rd query is going to do 2 seeks/scans/etc to find the row if Bar <> 1, but it might be faster in situations where it is already 1.

Answer (score 1):

The long answer is always that you need to test in your environment with a couple variations, even with easy stuff :) .

But the biggest factor you need to to consider is indexing.

If your table is indexed on that id field, that will make a huge difference compared to being indexed on some other, unrelated column.
If it is indexed on Bar and not Id, then the search for Bar <> 1 might help.

If were indexed on both (id, bar), that might be optimal for this update.
And that might make it truly irrelevant which of your statements you choose.

Check out the links in this highly-voted post:

[How to read an execution plan in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server)

Dump a bunch of records in your table on your target system, and try different combinations of

- indexing
- and queries

and see what you get.

Comment: Fragmentation, locking, indexing and caching makes it very hard to measure which is better.

Comment: I agree there might be a small number of situations where the Bar <> 1 might use an index on Bar that improves performance, but the optimizer might be smart enough to do this, and it would be a rare occurrence.

Comment: If you're talking about an existing system, then indeed you should trust that repeated tests that say they're similar means they're similar for now.  To know which indexes are really relevant, make sure you know what you have today, and then look at the execution plan when you run.

Comment: In an existing system, indeed all those things you mention are always there.  But when you look at "actual execution plan", you truly find out and don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first two queries will not produce the same results, unless all rows have an ID value =187.

The first query will update all the rows in your **Table** to have Bar=1 and ID = 187.
The second query will ensure that all rows with ID = 187 have a BAR value = 1

In general, the most simple SQL is a great place to start.

```
Update Foo SET BAR = 1 where ID = 187
```

As you performance tune, if there are a lot of rows that already have the BAR value = 1, then you could add:

```
WHERE BAR <> 1 and ID=187
```

to avoid extraneous updates, although engines may already optimize for this case, which is why starting with the most simple option and then analyze/tuning is generally best.

Comment: You caught a syntax issue (corrected with an edit), but I thought was obvious what I was trying to do.

Comment: While I agree that starting with the most simple option is best, I was hoping for some advice on analyzing/tuning.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using where bar<>1 because it will update all rows with id =187 whether they need to be updated or not.  Why update 923,498 rows when you only need to update 11? It is just a good habit to be to add the where <>  clause. Sure it won't make much difference in small updates, but if it is habit, you will not forget when you need to do a big one.

Comment: So you are saying you know that the optimizer can't account for this?  Or that you believe it is good practice just in case it can't?

Comment: I am saying I know for a fact that if you don't put this in here, you have told it to update them all, it is not something optimizer will take care of for you. You told it which records to update and it makes no assumptions about whether it is a good practice to update those records. I know this because I have seen these types of updates reflected in audit tables.  If you run the statement with the <> and without they will update a different number of records.  The bigger the table, the more critical it is to avoid wasted  processing.